# What is the right way to use "context:..." in an AJAX call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

So I'm aware that there are a big amount of threads about AJAX and the use of the context but after hours of reading and trying I open a new Thread.

So I have this (shorten version) javascript function:

```
this.CallService = function () {
    var Type = this.Type;
    var Url = this.Url;
    var Data = this.Data;
    var ContentType = this.ContentType;
    var DataType = this.DataType;
    var ProcessData = this.ProcessData;

    var ClipUrl = this.ClipUrl;
    var CountMax = this.CountMax;
    var Callback = this.Callback;

    var SucceededServiceCallback = this.SucceededServiceCallback;
    var FailedServiceCallback = this.FailedServiceCallback;


    return $.ajax({
        type: Type, //GET or POST or PUT or DELETE verb
        url: Url, // Location of the service
        data: Data, //Data sent to server
        contentType: ContentType, // content type sent to server
        dataType: DataType, //Expected data format from server
        processdata: ProcessData, //True or False
        context: this,
    }).done(function (msg) {//On Successfull service call
        SucceededServiceCallback(this, msg);
    }).fail(function (msg) {
        FailedServiceCallback(this, msg);
    });
}
```

The Important part here are the `context: this` and the two callbacks `done` and `fail`. Im those two callbacks I give the `this` context to my callback functions:

```
this.SucceededServiceCallback = function (context, result) {
    if (null != context) {
        UpdateDebugInfo(context, "succeeded: " + context.DataType + " URL: " + context.Url + " Data: " + context.Data + " Result: " +result);
    }
    if (context != null && context.DataType == "json" && result != null && context.Callback != null) {
        context.Callback(context, result);
    }
}
```

Here the important part is that I use the context to see access the variables DataType, Callback, Url etc.
The Problem now is that the context is set to the last context used (it's an asynchron call so all the variable are the variable from the last call). **So I'm pretty sure something is wrong with that `context: this,` part.** I just don't know how to use this right. Thanks for your help.

tl;dr:
I use `context: this` in an Ajax call. Context is always set to the last "this" called. I want to use the "this" of the call.

Comment: If i understand your issue, try: `context: $.extend({}, this),`

Comment: @A.Wolff that will clone his entire object, which may be overkill and could introduce other problems (eg: assuming they are the same object later on).  Best to just create an object containing the fields OP is interested in.

Comment: @AlexMcMillan I'm quite agree. Your answer is cleaner indeed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are "caching" all your variables before you fire each request, but in your `SucceededServiceCallback` function you are inspecting `this.XXX` - which is not the `var Type` it looks like you are expecting, but the actual `this.Type` itself.

What you could do is put these properties into an object and pass it as context, rather than your main object:

```
this.CallService = function () {
    var context = {
        Type : this.Type,
        Url : this.Url,
        Data : this.Data,
        ContentType : this.ContentType,
        DataType : this.DataType,
        ProcessData : this.ProcessData,
        ClipUrl : this.ClipUrl,
        CountMax : this.CountMax,
        Callback : this.Callback
    };

    var SucceededServiceCallback = this.SucceededServiceCallback;
    var FailedServiceCallback = this.FailedServiceCallback;

    return $.ajax({
        type: Type, //GET or POST or PUT or DELETE verb
        url: Url, // Location of the service
        data: Data, //Data sent to server
        contentType: ContentType, // content type sent to server
        dataType: DataType, //Expected data format from server
        processdata: ProcessData, //True or False
        context: context,
    }).done(function (msg) {//On Successfull service call
        SucceededServiceCallback(this, msg);
    }).fail(function (msg) {
        FailedServiceCallback(this, msg);
    });
}
```

Comment: So this version worked very well, thank you very much @Alex McMillan